# Inverse of a polynomials

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $f(x)=2x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_{4}[X]$ have inverse in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{4}[X]$? How to determine this polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $ax+b$ the inverse. Force: $$(2x+1)(ax+b) = 1 \implies 2ax^2+(a+2b)x+b = 1.$$
This suggests $b = 1$. And $a$ must satisfy: $$a +2\equiv0 \pmod 4 \quad \mbox{and} \quad 2a \equiv 0 \pmod 4.$$
Notice that $a = 2$ does the job. I leave you to check that $(2x+1)(2x+1) = 1$...